# Create report event in rds( amazon ) server

Tags: mysql, events, rds, into-outfile

I have a rds server in amazon . (mysql )
I want to create an event that run every week , execute query and save it to a csv file.

I have 2 problems :
1. When trying to create a file (with OUTFILE command) , i get an error:
    Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'%' to database 'dbName' (File_priv is false)
   How can i create a csv file using rds server ? where is the file saved ?
2. I can't create an event because i don't have permission for this action to my user  (Event_priv is set to false)

Is there a way i can perform this action on my rds server ?

thanks in advance

Comment: "file_priv is false". so grant that user the necessary privileges...

Comment: I can't grant file_priv using  mysql command . Can i do this using rds ?